# default pointer values in map when using operator[]

Tags: c++

Is a pointer inserted into a map due to a missing index always NULL?

```
std::map<int, Foo*> myMap;
Foo* myFoo = myMap[0];
```

Is myFoo guaranteed to be NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned

So yes, this is guaranteed to be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when a missing index is accessed, it is value-initialized, implying a null pointer is returned in this case (as it is a scalar value).

Source : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at